# If $f$ is uniformly continuous on two sets, show that $f$ is also uniformly continuous on the union of two given sets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

So my next question is again about uniform continuity. Can you give me hints, or (better) give the solution of the following exercise? Thank you very much :-)

> Given two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb R$ with $A$ bounded from above (i.e., having an upper bound) and $B$ bounded from below (i.e., having a lower bound), where
>   $\sup A = \inf B$ and $\sup A \in A\cap B$
>
> **(1)** Prove that $A\cap B = \{\sup A\}.$
>
> Now, take $A$ and $B$ as above. Let $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and assume that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ and on $B$.
>
> **(2)** Prove that f is uniformly continuous on $A \cup B.$

My try:

(1) Let $x \in A\cap B$. Because $\sup A = \inf B,$ $\inf B \le x \le \sup A$ implies $x = \sup A$. I chose $x$ arbitrary, so $ A\cap B = \sup A$

(2) ???

Comment: Start by writing down what "uniformly continuous" means.

Comment: Uniformly continuous means that given an epsilon > 0, a single delta>0 can be chosen that works simultaneously for all points c in A and B.

Comment: This doesn't hold in the infinite case e.g. $f(x)=1/x$ and $I_n=[1/n,1]$, the infinite union is $(0,1]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition says $\forall\varepsilon>0\  \exists\delta>0\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$.  To prove that a function is uniformly continuous, you need to find $\delta$ as a function of $\varepsilon$ and prove that it's small enough.  You know you've got $\delta_1$ that's small enough on one set and $\delta_2$ that's small enough on the other.  Which one is smaller might depend on $\varepsilon$.  However $\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ will be small enough on both sets.

**Later note, per comments:**  Let's make $\delta_A$ small enough so that if $x,y\in A$ and $|x-y|<\delta_A$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/2$, and if $x,y\in B$ and $|x-y|<\delta_B$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/2$.

Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_A,\delta_B\}$.

If $x,y\text{ both}\in A$ or $\text{both}\in B$, and $|x-y|<\delta$ that does it, as above.

If $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, then the distances from $x$ to the boundary point $b$, and from $y$ to $b$, are less than $\delta$, so
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \le|f(x)-f(b)|+|f(b)-f(y)|<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon.$$

So in all cases, $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @MichealHardy: Dont we have to talk about the connectedness of A and B?

Comment: Suppose we let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$.  Maybe the remaining issue is this: what if $|x-y|<\delta$ and $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.  The argument I gave above works if $x,y\in A$ or $x,y\in B$.  Let $b$ be that boundary point between $A$ and $B$, which, under your hypotheses, is a limit point of both sets.  Then $x$ differs from $b$ by less than $\delta$ and $y$ differs from $b$ by less than $\delta$, so each of $f(x)$, $f(y)$ differs from $b$ by less than $\varepsilon$, so $|f(x)-f(y)|<2\varepsilon$.  Not good enough, so here's what I propose to do: [out of space; continued below]

Comment: Pick $\delta_1$, $\delta_2$ as in my answer, except make them small enough to guarantee $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/2$ instead of $<\varepsilon$.  That will take care of all three cases: both points in $A$, both in $B$, and one in $A$ and one in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

So the formal answer should be as follows?:

### Part 1

Let $x$ $\in A\cap B$. Because sup A = inf B  , $\inf B \le x \le \sup A$ implies $x = \sup A$. I chose x arbitrary, so $ A\cap B = \sup A$

### Part 2

**f** is uniformly continuous on A. This means that for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a $\delta_1 \gt 0$ such that $|x-y|\lt \delta_1$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$ for every $x,y$ $\in$ A. Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Let $\delta_1 $ = $g_1$($\epsilon$), which is small enough to work for the given $\epsilon$

**f** is uniformly continuous on B. This means that for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a $\delta_2 \gt 0$ such that $|x-y|\lt \delta_2$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$  for every $x,y$ $\in$ B.  Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Let $\delta_2 $ = $g_2$($\epsilon$), which is small enough to work for the given $\epsilon$

Now consider $f$ on the domain of $A \cup B$. Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Choose $\delta = \min\left \{\delta_1, \delta_2  \right \}$.

Because A and B are connected, and continuous functions preserve connected sets, we can use this $\delta$ for any given $\epsilon>0 $.Namely, for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a $\delta =\min\left \{\delta_1, \delta_2  \right \} \gt 0$ such that $|x-y|\lt \delta=\min\left \{\delta_1, \delta_2  \right \}$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$ for every $x,y$ $\in$ $A\cup B$, concluding that f is uniformly continuous on $A \cup B$

Comment: I changed \text{sup A} to \sup A.  That is standard.  It doesn't just prevent italicization of "sup" it also provides proper spacing in things like $5\sup A$, and in a "displayed" setting, it affects positions of subscripts, thus: $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in A}$.  And there's no reason for the $A$ to be within \text{}.  Similarly I changed min to \min.