# Is $f:(-1,1)\to R$ defined as $f(x)= \frac{x}{1-\lvert x \rvert}$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ uniformly continuos?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

I think this fuction is uniformly continuos, but the inverse is not since the limit in the proximities to $\lvert x \rvert = 1$ the function has a vertical asymptote.

However I tried a lot of algebra to prove the inverse function is uniformly continuos, but with no luck. Any Hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function cannot be uniformly continuous on the interval $(-1,1)$ due to the vertical asymptotes; you would have to cut back to $(-1+\epsilon, 1-\delta)$ in order to recover uniform continuity. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600623/whats-the-fastest-way-to-tell-if-a-function-is-uniformly-continuous-or-not) post for some more tricks.

EDIT: To address the flip side of this problem, note that $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (-1,1)$ can be written out explictly:
$$
f^{-1}(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{x}{1-x} & \quad x < 0 \\
            0 & \quad x=0 \\
            \frac{x}{1+x} & \quad x > 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

On the intervals $(-\infty,-2]$ and $[2,\infty)$ note that $f^{-1}$ has a bounded derivative. Thus we know that $f^{-1}$ is uniformly continuous there. The interval $[-2,2]$ is compact and the function $f^{-1}$ is continuous on that interval, and thus is uniformly continuous on that interval. Finally, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217683/if-f-is-unformly-continuous-on-two-sets-show-that-f-is-also-uniformly-continuou) post shows us that a function which is uniformly continuous on finitely many adjacent intervals is also uniformly continuous on their union.

Comment: Yeah, its the case with the inverse where I'm struggling.

Comment: @MariaGuthier Okay, I will attempt to address your other question as well, but you should still edit your post to indicate that you are not trying to prove the uniform continuity of the function $f$, since it isn't uniformly continuous.

Comment: But I think it can be useful for people reading Mathexchange. But I edited so its less confusing!

Comment: @MariaGuthier I have added text addressing the 2nd part of your question.

Answer (score 4):

Your function $f$ is not uniformly continuous. To see why, recall that a uniformly continuous function preserves Cauchy sequences but you can take a sequence $a_n\in(-1,1)$ such that $a_n\to 1$ but $f(a_n)\to\infty$, henece $f$ cannot be unifromly continuous.

Comment: I know is the other case when I don't know how to prove uniformly continuity.

Comment: @MariaGuthier I don't understand your question then. Could you edit it to make it more understandable?