# Uniform continunity on any closed subset means continunity?

Tags: calculus

If a function $f$ on a open set $U$ is uniformly continuous on any closed subset, then is it continuous?

I find that the uniform continunity can be “summed” on finite sets([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217683/if-f-is-unformly-continuous-on-two-sets-show-that-f-is-also-uniformly-continuou)). But it is a problem that $U$ may not be represented by finite cover of closed subset.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forums. It would probably be good if you provided a bit more context, and shared at least some of your own thoughts and/or attempts to answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, what I figured has been added below. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably $f$ is a function from an open subset $U$ of a metric space to a metric space, otherwise "uniform continuity" doesn't mean anything. Metric spaces are regular spaces, so if $x\in U$ there is an open $V$ with $x\in V\subset \overline V\subset U.$ And $f$ restricted to $\overline V$ is continuous by hypothesis.

A function $f$ such that  every $x\in dom(f)$ has a  nbhd $W$  such that $f|_W$ is continuous is called a locally continuous function. (A nbhd of $x$ is any $W$ such that $x\in V\subset W$ for some open $V$.)

There are many properties of continuous functions (between any spaces) that are equivalent to continuity. One of them is:

$f$ is continuous iff $f$ is locally continuous.

Remark: If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $x\in U\subset X$ where $U$ is open in $X$ then for some $r>0$ the open ball $B_d(x,r)$ is a subset of $U.$ Now if $V=B_d(x,r/2)$ then $x\in V\subset \overline V\subset U.$

Comment: I don't disagree with your answer, but I also do not think it is too helpful since this question presumably is at an undergraduate real analysis course which would not be familiar with topological concepts such as regular spaces.

Comment: I wrote "$f$ restricted to $\overline V$ instead of $f|_{\overline V}$ because even 3 feet from a 50" screen it's hard to tell f|_V from  f|_{\overline V}, i.e. $f|_V$ and $f|_{\overline V}$.

Comment: @Math1000 .That is why I included the Remark.